Why doesn't the Response object automatically include Content-Length?
A Response object will automatically include Content-Type in headers when given a Blob. Why doesn't it automatically include Content-Length?

I haven't found any authoritative source, but I guess the idea is that the Content-Length  header is the responsibility of the code actually sending the Response object. It's not necessarily known up front, but is subject to encoding/compression or ranged requests.
